# How can I copy a data of one folder from Blob Storage to another Blob Storage in python code?

Tags: python, powershell, azure-functions, azure-data-factory, azure-function-app

I want to copy data of one folder from a particular blob storage to another blob storage.

I want to write a python code in Azure Function to copy the data of a particular folder, also I want to write a python code to convert hot tier file into archive tier blob storage.

Please suggest me the code to do this.

Comment: Hi, did you have a try of the link I give? Can you work it out now?

Comment: Hi, I have tried this link, But this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to copy the blob:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#start-copy-from-url-source-url--metadata-none--incremental-copy-false----kwargs-

Use these to set the tier:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#set-premium-page-blob-tier-premium-page-blob-tier----kwargs-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?view=azure-python#set-standard-blob-tier-standard-blob-tier----kwargs-